# How to remove Ubuntu 15.10 from a multiboot configuration?

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10

How can I remove Ubuntu 15.10 from a multiboot computer with windows 10 Ubuntu Kylin and Deepin 2014.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove an OS from within another OS. How you do that from Windows or from Deepin is off topic.

From Ubuntu Kylin: start gParted, select the partitions with Ubuntu and delete them. Mind to check twice before you delete it that it is the correct one you delete. I have no idea what Deepin has as a description inside gParted but your Ubuntu 15.10 will be named actually "Ubuntu 15.10". If you need the actual partitions the easiest way is to boot up 15.10 and check `df  -h` or `more /etc/fstab`. Mind also that if you shared partitions between the OS's to not remove that one.